# T-SQL: transposing rows into columns based on a range

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I have a table, Members, containing a list of member IDs.

I need a query that will return two columns, showing the start and end ID of each range from the list.

Please see the example screenshot, which should provide more clarity.

[image: Example here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you assign each record in your `Members` table a row number, where the lowest member ID is row 1, the next lowest is row 2, etc. You'd have something like this:

```
MemberID  RowNumber
123       1
124       2
125       3
211       4
212       5
214       6
320       7
321       8
322       9
```

The difference between `RowNumber` values for two consecutive rows is always one, whereas the difference between `MemberID` values for two consecutive rows, assuming that no value is repeated in your original table, is always *at least* one. So consider how the expression `MemberID - RowNumber` behaves as you go through the table: the value of that expression for two consecutive rows will be the same if and only if their `MemberID`s differ by exactly one; otherwise, the value will be larger for the second row than for the first. Call this expression `GroupNumber`.

```
MemberID  RowNumber  GroupNumber
123       1          122
124       2          122
125       3          122
211       4          207
212       5          207
214       6          208
320       7          313
321       8          313
322       9          313
```

The distinct `GroupNumber` values exactly identify the contiguous ranges of values that you're interested in. So all you have to do is write a simple query that produces the `GroupNumber` as described here, and then group the results on that value to get what you want:

```
declare @Members table (MemberID bigint);
insert @Members values (123), (124), (125), (211), (212), (214), (320), (321), (322);

with GroupedMembers as
(
    select
        M.MemberID,
        GroupNumber = M.MemberID - row_number() over (order by MemberID)
    from
        @Members M
)
select
    FromID = min(G.MemberID),
    ToID = max(G.MemberID)
from
    GroupedMembers G
group by
    G.GroupNumber
order by
    G.GroupNumber;
```

Results:

```
FromID  ToID
123     125
211     212
214     214
320     322
```

Comment: Excellent. I was thinking of something along the lines of rownumber, but was struggling with the next part. This is most useful, thank you, Joe!